# compactenss on function spaces of the form $\mathbb{R}^X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}_+$ a countable set. We consider the space of functions 
$\mathbb{R}^X$, i.e. $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ with the topology of pointwise convergence. Let $A_C\subset X$ all functions such that $\frac{|g(x)|}{(1+x)^p}\le C, \forall x\in X$. My notes say, since $X$ is countable the space $A_C\subset X$ is compact. Why is this true? Is there a general result from topology, which guarantees compactness in this case? Note, by the definition of the space $A_C$, we can define a norm $\|g\|:=\sup_{x\in X} \frac{|g(x)|}{(1+x)^p}$ and then we have $g\in A_C\iff \|g\|\le C$. I'm not sure if this is also used for compactness. A reference or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $p$? $\,$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $p$ is a constant $p>2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $x\in X$ let $I_x$ be the closed interval in $\Bbb R$ given by

$$I_x=\left[-C(1+x)^p,C(1+x)^p\right]\;.$$

Then $$\frac{|g(x)|}{(1+x)^p}\le C$$ if and only if $g(x)\in I_x$, so

$$A_C=\prod_{x\in X}I_x\;.$$

Closed intervals in $\Bbb R$ are compact, so $A$ is a product of compact sets and is therefore compact in the product topology on $\Bbb R^X$. And the topology of pointwise convergence on $\Bbb R^X$ is just the ordinary Tikhonov product topology on the product $\Bbb R^X$, so $A_C$ is compact in it.

Comment: Just one small question: Where do we use that $X$ is countable? For Tikhonov we don't need a countable product.

Comment: @hulik: So far as I can see, the countability of $X$ doesn’t make any difference here. It does ensure that $\Bbb R^X$ is metrizable in the product topology, which might be used later.