# Continuity of functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is a follow up question to this previous [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578966/compactenss-on-function-spaces-of-the-form-mathbbrx). Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}_+$, where $X$ is countable and we are considering the space $\mathbb{R}^X$ of functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ with the topology of pointwise convergence. Let $A_C\subset X$ all functions such that $\frac{|f(x)|}{(1+x)^p}\le C, \forall x\in X$ and define the norm $\|f\|:=\sup_{x\in X}\frac{|f(x)|}{(1+x)^p}$. The space $A_C$ is compact (see the previous question above). We define the following functional, $G:A_C\to\mathbb{R}$

$$G(f):=\int f(s) \mu(ds)+F(f)$$

where $F:A_C\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex and positively homogeneous functional such that for any $f_n\to f$ pointwise, we have $F(f)\ge \lim\sup F(f_n)$ and $\mu$ is a finite measure. Clearly $G$ is also a convex functional. I want to prove continuity of $G$, which should follow from convexity and the dominated convergence theorem. Here we assume that $x^p$ is $\mu$-integrable.

Since $A_C$ is first countable continuity and sequentially continuity are the same. So let $f_n\to f$ pointwise and we must prove that $G(f_n)\to G(f)$. By the definition of $A_C$ we can interchange the integral and limit by the dominated convergence theorem:

$$\lim_n G(f_n)=\lim_n\int f_n(s)\mu(ds)+\lim_n F(f_n)=\int f(s) \mu(ds)+\lim_nF(f_n)$$

if all the limits exist. But how can I use convexity to complete the proof?